# Authenticate via Ruby into Jira

Tags: ruby, authentication, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api

Authenticate via Ruby into Jira and post changes via ZAPI (Zephyr API)

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to authenticate via Ruby into Jira and then make changes to Zephyr (Jira plugin w/Z(ephyr)API) issues.

I'm trying to execute this code (taken from: http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#executionresourceapis)

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'rest_client'
values   = "{\n    \"issueId\": 10600,\n    \"versionId\": \"10000\",\n    \"cycleId\": \"16\",\n    \"projectId\": 10000\n}"
headers  = {:content_type => "application/json"}
response = RestClient.post "http://getzephyr.apiary-mock.com/jira_server/rest/zapi/latest/execution", values, headers
puts response
```

**My main issue is I cannot authenticate my Jira instance via Ruby. My attempts include (among countless others):**

**A) I think this works** (even though this works, I don't think it'll work for my use b/c I need to pass in other values to change Jira/Zephyr tickets):

```
curl -D- -u fyousuf:password -X GET -H Content-Type: application/json http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution
```

(tried curl via https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication)

**A) Output:**

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.11
Date: Wed, 06 Aug 2014 20:14:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-AREQUESTID: 974x1935522x1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5F5D8411206C9B99054CABAD93AAE715; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=A8NH-S9GW-2ZYX-9R4V|a6024d3cb5c5585d2b6f765001ebfefa67dd5a7a|lin; Path=/
X-ASESSIONID: 1x3gunc
X-AUSERNAME: fyousuf
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform

{"status":{"1":{"id":1,"color":"#75B000","description":"Test was executed and passed successfully.","name":"PASS"},"2":{"id":2,"color":"#CC3300","description":"Test was executed and failed.","name":"FAIL"},"3":{"id":3,"color":"#F2B000","description":"Test execution is a work-in-progress.","name":"WIP"},"4":{"id":4,"color":"#6693B0","description":"The test execution of this test was blocked for some reason.","name":"BLOCKED"},"-1":{"id":-1,"color":"#A0A0A0","description":"The test has not yet been executed.","name":"UNEXECUTED"}},"executions":[],"currentlySelectedExecutionId":""}
```

**B) This doesn't work:**

```
  values   = "{\n    \"issueId\": 32640,\n    \"versionId\": \"11163\",\n    \"cycleId\": \"5\",\n    \"projectId\": 10460\n,\n    \"status\": \"1\"}"
  headers  = {:content_type => "application/json"}

  auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode64( 'fyousuf:password' ).chomp
  url = 'http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution'

  resource = RestClient::Resource.new( url )
  response = resource.post( :Authorization => auth )
  #response = resource.post "http://jira.test.local/rest/zapi/latest/execution", values, headers
  puts response
  puts response.code
```

**B) Output:**

```
 {"errorDesc":"You do not have the permission to make this request. Login Required.","errorId":"ERROR"}
      200
```

I'm thinking that if I'm able to authenticate into Jira with 'curl' then via Ruby should work too, but not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

to access Jira's API from Ruby I use following construction. The net/http object does the work. For clearity I removed error-handling and logging from the example.

```
   require 'net/http'
   require 'json'

   http = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
   resp = nil
   http.start do |http|
     req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(api call + parameter)
     req.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json') if "POST" == req.method
     req.add_field('Accept', 'application/json')
     # we make an HTTP basic auth by passing the
     # username and password
     req.basic_auth username, password
     resp = http.request(req)
   end
   return resp.body
```